# Firebase Auth Facebook Login error: "It looks like this app isn't available"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3, facebook-login, quasar

I am working on a VUE3 app with Quasar and Firebase and Google Sign-In works just fine, however I am having t rouble implementing Facebook Login. Whenever a sign-in through Facebook is attempted I get the error: "It looks like this app isn't available".

Here is the code relevant to the FB sign-in method:

```js
async function registerUserFacebook() {
  const screenSize = window.innerWidth;

  if (screenSize > 600) {
    signInWithPopup(auth, providerFb)
      .then(async (result) => {
        const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;

        const user = result.user;

        const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
        } else {
          setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
            displayName: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            userType: "Persona",
            role: "user",
            uid: user.uid,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            favorites: [],
            imgSrc: {},
            rating: [],
          }).catch((error) => {});
        }

        getCurrentUserInfo(user.uid);

        router.push({ name: "home" });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;

        const errorMessage = error.message;

        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      });
  } else {
    signInWithRedirect(auth, providerFb)
      .then(async (result) => {
        const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;

        const user = result.user;

        const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
        } else {
          setDoc(doc(db, "users", user.uid), {
            displayName: user.displayName,
            email: user.email,
            userType: "Persona",
            role: "user",
            uid: user.uid,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            favorites: [],
            imgSrc: {},
            rating: [],
          }).catch((error) => {});
        }

        getCurrentUserInfo(user.uid);

        router.push({ name: "home" });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;

        const errorMessage = error.message;

        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      });
  }
}
```

I suspect this has more to do with the settings in Facebook for Developers. Here is what I have checked/attempted:

1. I have made sure the App ID and App Secret in FB Developer settings and in the Firebase config match.
2. The app is in LIVE MODE
3. email and public_profile are set to ADVANCED ACCESS
4. App Domain and OAuth Redirect URI are also in order and match the Firebase config.

What else could I be missing here?